# Insert Rows Between Specific Rows in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

By using Data from another sheet I need to insert rows.

For example, if there are data in column 10 using values from those cells as row number I need to insert columns.

[image: Example]

This is the code I have and it wont work

```
Sheets("Input").Select
Rows("11:11").Select
Selection.Copy

Dim x As Integer
For x = 1 To 12

Dim Hdr As Integer

Hdr = Worksheets("Input").Cells(10, x).Value

Sheets("Data Table").Select
Rows("Hdr:Hdr").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Next x
```

Comment: What about this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: Could you share the screenshot of the `Data Table` worksheet and better explain what needs to be done? It looks like you're mixing rows and columns.

Comment: " if there are data in **column 10**" ? `Hdr = Worksheets("Input").Cells(10, x).Value` refers to **row 10**. "I need to insert columns." ? `Rows("Hdr:Hdr").Select: Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown` is inserting **rows**. Probably should be just `Rows(Hdr).Select`.

Comment: Yes it was rows I needed to insert. thank you for your help. your code works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

avoid Select/Selection and use explicit references to object
use `Rows(Hdr)`

```
With Worksheets("Input") ' reference "Input" sheet

    .Rows("11:11").Copy ' copy referenced sheet row 11

    Dim x As Long
    For x = 1 To 12
    
        Dim Hdr As Long
        Hdr = .Cells(10, x).Value ' store the value in referenced sheet cell in row 10 and column x
        
        Sheets("Data Table").Rows(Hdr).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Next

End With
```

Comment: These works. Thank you!